# Attempting to use execvpe(...) but get implicit declaration error - even though I think I'm using the correct argument types

Tags: c, linux, exec, posix, unistd.h

I am getting the following warning when I compile:

```
execute.c:20:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘execvpe’[-Wimplicit-function-declaration] execvpe("ls", args, envp);
```

^

My understanding is that this occurs when the function you are trying to use has the incorrect types of arguments. However, I am pretty sure that I am supplying the correct arguments to:

```
int execvpe(const char *file, char *const argv[], char *const envp[]);
```

as described in the [Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execvpe)

Here are the relevant parts of my code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void test_execvpe(char* envp[])
{
    const char* temp = getenv("PATH");
    char path[strlen(temp)+1];
    strcpy(path, temp);
    printf("envp[%d] = %s\n", 23, envp[23]); //print PATH
    char* args[] = {"-l", "/usr", (char*) NULL};
    execvpe("ls", args, envp);
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[], char* envp[])
{

    //test_execlp();
    test_execvpe(envp);
    return 0;

}
```

Anyone know why I keep getting this error? Thanks!

Comment: Add #define _GNU_SOURCE before the #include of unistd.h.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will look this up. Do you have quick explanation as to why this is needed?

Comment: It's a GNU extension. It is mentioned on the man page.

Comment: One more followup question for you. The argument "-l" does not seem to be added to the command "ls" - the output is as if I typed "ls /usr" in the command shell.

bin  games  include  lib  local  sbin  share  src

It just skips over the "-l"

Comment: The first arg in args should be argv[0]. Use something like "{"ls" , "-l", "/usr", (char*) NULL}"

Comment: Hmm, thanks for that! I remember reading about that yesterday. I should have made the connection. Last question: How you know all this off the top of your head? Thanks!

Comment: Smile. I started using Unix with V7. Slashdot is getting mad at me for extended comments. V7 was a long time ago.

Comment: And of course by slashdot I meant Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

"implicit declaration of function" means the compiler has not seen a declaration for that function.  Most compilers, including gcc, will assume that the way the function has been used is correct and the return type is an `int`.  This is generally a bad idea.  Even if you use the arguments correctly it will still throw this error as the compiler does not know you are using the arguments correctly.  The declaration of `execvpe` is only included if `_GNU_SOURCE` is defined before including unistd.h as it is a GNU extension.

You will want something like:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>
```